Sharing same function between two view models?
I have a view which I use throughout my app on various pages. The view shows an image and a label, in this case the city name.
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct CityView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var cityViewModel: CityViewModel
    
    @Binding var city: City
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CityDetailView(cityId: city.id)) {
            VStack {
                KFImage(URL(string: city.photoUrl ?? ""))
                    .resizable()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    
                Text(city.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

Now, if the API response sends a nil image, I want to call a separate endpoint to fetch the image url. This endpoint is currently set up to fetch a stock photo url and return it.
Right now, I have two different pages:

A page that shows a list of random cities
A profile page that shows a list of cities that the user has saved

For the page that shows a list of random cities, I have the following view model:
class CityViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let cityService: CityServiceProtocol
    
    @Published var cities: [City] = []

    func fetchPhoto(cityId: Int) async {
        do {
            let data = try await cityService.getPhoto(cityId: cityId)
            guard let photoUrl = data.data?.photoUrl else { return }
            
            // Update the image url
            if let index = self.cities.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == cityId }) {
                self.cities[index].photoUrl = photoUrl
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
}

As you can see, I already have the fetchPhoto() function here which updates the city image url once returned.
For the profile page that shows a list of cities that the user has saved, I have the following view model:
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let profileService: ProfileServiceProtocol
    
    @Published var savedCities: [City] = []

    // excluded function that fetches saved cities from the api
}

Now I've run into a problem where, if the user navigates to their profile to view their saved cities, and a city doesn't have an image url, it doesn't currently fetch the image from the api.
If I want to keep this structure of using two view models, would I have to copy the fetchPhoto() function from the CityViewModel to the ProfileViewModel, or is it possible to have one function that updates both view models?

Put it in a shared manager

Yes, I would create a PhotosService or similar and provide an instance of this object to both "view models".  You could also probably refactor your approach to "view models". Generally, in SwiftUI the view is the view model. You could provide both views with a single model with that model having cities and savedCities properties. This will probably also simplify operations like saving and unsaving a city from the list view

Your view models are already basically the same from the code shown. Can you show your protocol differences? If nothing else you could probably keep the top view model with two initializers and some logic to separate the first properties. You could even do an initial with a generic probably.

I see two problems in your original code: first,  since fetchPhoto() is asynchronous, it can potentially overlap. A network request (and Tasks in Swift as well) however do not guarantee that the order of incoming results matches the order of sent request. In other words, the last incoming request wins the race, even if this is not the most recent data. Secondly, when you receive nil as the result of the URL, you simply return, but you should handle this case as well, since the URL is indeed updated, i.e. it became nil. To solve it, you need better fine-grained state management.

Hint: a ViewModel is never shared and observed by several views – only by one.
However, a proper ViewModel can observe a shared Model. You may not even need a ViewModel as an Observable object, since any ViewModel can be implemented as a SwiftUI view, whose child view is the actual view, and the child view receives the state from its parent.

You could have one model store object that is shared between the views. The async funcs could be in a controller struct (usually in the environment so it can be mocked for previews) and can be called from both views (in .task(id:)) and pass in the model object for it to update. Eg
struct Controller: ControllerProtocol {
    
    func fetchPhoto(cityId: City.ID, model: Model) async {

    func fetchCities(model: Model) async {



The logic could look something like this.
struct City {
    var id: Int
    var photoUrl: URL
}

struct Photo {
    var data: PhotoData?

    struct PhotoData {
         var photoUrl: URL
    }
}

struct SomeService: Service {
    func getPhoto(cityId: Int) async throws -> Photo {
        Photo()
     }
}

protocol Service {
    func getPhoto(cityId: Int) async throws -> Photo
}

 class ViewModel<T: Service>: ObservableObject {
     let service: T
     @Published var cities: [City] = []

     init(service: T) {
        self.service = service
     }

    func fetchPhoto(cityId: Int) async {
        do {
            let photo = try await service.getPhoto(cityId: cityId)
             guard let photoUrl = photo.data?.photoUrl else { return }

            // Update the image url
             if let index = self.cities.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == cityId }) {
                self.cities[index].photoUrl = photoUrl
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
}

@ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel(service: SomeService())

Even if you had to make a second protocol to support it. If you post the two protocols there may be a way to merge them though.
